# Old fluid sim data appears in new blend file

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation

[image]

Ok, so my fluid domain automatically takes the form it took in a completely different project I did every time I try to use it. It starts out like below then ends up like the one above. I've deleted the project that one is from so I have no idea why it is still doing this. It happens in every project I create a fluid domain in. I need help!! [image]

Comment: look for the folder that has the simulation's cache and delete it.